# Arduino: issue running the same code in loop() and in custom function

Tags: c++, string, loops, arduino, char

Practicing with some Arduino code, I've encountered an unexpected behavior trying to run the same code in `loop()` and in a custom `myfunction()`.

After some long trial-and-error I prepared this minimal code to replicate the issue (tested with Arduino UNO).
Essentialy, for each character of a given string, the code should return the corresponding index in a char array. For a given index I also return the array value through the function `getCharByIndex`.

```c
char* dict[] = {
  "a", "b", "c"
};

char txtorigin[] = "abc";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {

  Serial.println( "" );
  Serial.println( "My function: first call" );
  myfunction(1);
  
  int run_loop = 1;
  if(run_loop == 1){
    Serial.println( "" );
    Serial.println( "Loop code" );
    uint8_t sizeofarray = sizeof(txtorigin) - 1 ;
    char c;
    uint8_t idx;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<sizeofarray; i++) {
      c = txtorigin[i];
      idx = getIndexOf( &c );
      Serial.print(c);
      Serial.print(" index: ");
      Serial.print( idx );
      Serial.print(" char: ");
      Serial.print( getCharByIndex( idx ) );
      Serial.println( "" );
    }
  }

  Serial.println( "" );
  Serial.println( "My function: second call" );
  myfunction(1);
  
  delay(1000 * 60);

}

void myfunction(const int something)
{

  uint8_t sizeofarray = sizeof(txtorigin) - 1 ;
  char c;
  int idx;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i<sizeofarray; i++) {
    c = txtorigin[i];
    idx = getIndexOf( &c );
    Serial.print(c);
    Serial.print(" index: ");
    Serial.print( idx );
    Serial.print(" char: ");
    Serial.print( getCharByIndex( idx ) );
    Serial.println( "" );
  } 
}

int getIndexOf( const char * dict_val )
{
  for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < sizeof( dict ) / sizeof( char * ); i++ )
    if ( !strcmp( dict_val, dict[i] ) )
      return i;
      
  return -1;
}

char* getCharByIndex( int any_idx) 
{
   int idx = any_idx % sizeof(dict);
   return dict[idx];
}
```

The function `getIndexOf` should return the `dict[]` index of a given char*.

When `run_loop` is 1 I get the following output:

```
My function: first call
a index: -1 char: 
b index: -1 char: 
c index: -1 char: 

Loop code
a index: 0 char: a
b index: 1 char: b
c index: 2 char: c

My function: second call
a index: -1 char: 
b index: -1 char: 
c index: -1 char:
```

When `run_loop` is 0 I get the following output:

```
My function: first call
a index: 0 char: a
b index: 1 char: b
c index: 2 char: c

My function: second call
a index: 0 char: a
b index: 1 char: b
c index: 2 char: c
```

I honestly don't understand what is going on there. I suspect that the function `getIndexOf` might be the one creating some problem but I don't have an explanation.

Any help would be very appreciated.

---

EDIT: what each function is supposed to do? (following the comment from Gabriel Staples)

`getIndexOf`: I would need a function that, given a value (from `char txtorigin[] = "abc";`), returns the corresponding index of char* dict[].
Ideally:

```
char c;
int idx;
c = txtorigin[i];
idx = getIndexOf( &c );
```

`getCharByIndex`: This function should return the value of dict[] corresponding to an index that can be greater that the size of dict[].
Ideally:

```
getCharByIndex( 5 ) -> "b"
```

`myfunction`: This is just to check how everything is working.

Comment: There's nothing really Arduino specific here.  Did it ever occur to you to simply debug this C++ code on an actual computer with an IDE and a debugger?

Comment: If you build outside of the IDE and use a software debugger, I recommend building the code with `-ggdb -O0` to buid with gdb debug symbols on and optimization off, then use the gdbgui debugger in your browser: https://www.gdbgui.com/.

Comment: Please add comments to describe what each function is supposed to do.

Comment: What's the purpose of this strange code ? Is `getIndexof` supposed to work with single characters, or with longer *texts* (`const char*`) ?  &c isn't such a *text*. And "b" isn't a single char.

Comment: `sizeof(dict)` depends on the size of a pointer, which depends on the type of arduino. I guess it is not what you want, anyway.

Comment: @datafiddler I can agree that is a strange code and I'm aware to know not so much of C/C++. `getIndexOf` is supposed to work with single characters like "b" taken from some `const char*` like "abc". So, formally, not single char.

Comment: In C / C++ "b" is a string of two characters: `const char* text_b { 'b', '\0'};` (including a terminator), and `'b'` is a single char, the same as your `dict[1][0]`. Your `dict` is an array of pointers...  The relation between arrays and pointers is essential for understanding C and C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Essentialy, for each character of a given string, the code should
> return the corresponding index in a char array.

```
const char* dict = "*abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // ( a -> 1 ... z -> 26 )

int find (char c, const char* dict) {
  const char *p = dict;
  while (*p) { 
    if (*p == c) return p-dict; 
    else p++;
  }
  return -1; 
}

const char* test = "hello";   

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   int len = strlen(test);
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      int idx = find(test[i], dict);
      if (idx > 0) Serial.println(idx); 
   } 
}

void loop() { }
```

Comment: Thank you. I adapted my code to your solution and I get no unexpected results now. I still not fully understand how calling my version of `find(...)` in `loop()` was generating both wrong and write results but at least I can go further.

Answer (score 0):

> Arduino: issue running the same code in loop() and in custom function

The point is that the code is not really the same.

In `loop()` you have

```
uint8_t idx;
```

While in `myfunction()` you have

```
int idx;
```

Since the size of `int` varies according to the platform, it is likely that whatever you are trying to store does not fall into the range.

See:
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30749/int-vs-uint8-t-vs-uint16-t

Comment: Thanks, that was left by mistake. Unfortunately it does not solve the problem with my code. If I correct into `int idx;` for both functions I get results like `a index: -1 char: `. If I correct into `uint8_t idx;` for both functions I get results like `a index: 255 char:`. The correct result would be `a index: 0 char: a`.